# Post Array to BatchBlock

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am trying Push some data to a BatchBlock and I need to pass it one by one in foreach loop. I tried to search some method to pass an array to batchBlock but I didn't find any method like it.

Is there any method or work around to accept array, if not what is the reason to not include this functionality.

```
var modelsDataTable = modelsAndFormulasDataSet.Tables[0];

foreach (DataRow row in modelsDataTable.Rows)
{
modelIdsBatchBlock.Target1.Post<long>(row.Field<long>(AppConstants.ModelsDataTable.ModelId.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you need to do this, this may be a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? But in short you could make the type argument of the batch block an array instead of long, e.g. `new BatchBlock<long[]>()`.

Comment: if I initialize like var batchBlock = new BatchBlock<long[]>(3) and then batchBlock.post(new long[5](){1,2,3,4,5}); it will dispatch after 3 arrays has been posted to batchblock, 3 arrays of length 5 means it will dispatch after 15 values has been entered. but I want only 3 values to be dispatched.

Comment: Your exactly correct. So what exactly is the behavior you do you want? Are you saying you want to post an array and have the block output groups of three?

Comment: one situation which I have is like, var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<int, List<long>>, TransformBlock returns  List<long> and I linked it to BatchBlock transformBlock.LinkTo(batchBlock) and batchBlock should process values when batchsized reached to 3 values not 15 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for clarifying the question. Based on this desired behavior:

> one situation which I have is like, `var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<int, List<long>>`, `TransformBlock` returns `List<long>` and I linked it to `BatchBlock transformBlock.LinkTo(batchBlock)` and `batchBlock` should process values when batchsized reached to 3 values not 15 values.

What you're looking for is a `TransformManyBlock`. Here's an example the simulates your desired behavior in an NUnit test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class BlockTester
{
    [Test]
    public async Task BuildPipeline()
    {
        var inputBlock = new TransformBlock<int, List<long>>(x => Enumerable.Repeat((long)0, 6).ToList());
        var xFormBlock = new TransformManyBlock<List<long>, long>(x => x);
        var batchBlock = new BatchBlock<long>(3);
        var testBlock = new ActionBlock<long[]>(x => Assert.AreEqual(3, x.Length));

        inputBlock.LinkTo(xFormBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
        xFormBlock.LinkTo(batchBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
        batchBlock.LinkTo(testBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

        await inputBlock.SendAsync(1);
        await inputBlock.SendAsync(2);
        await inputBlock.SendAsync(3);

        inputBlock.Complete();
        await testBlock.Completion;
    }
}
```